# Displaying a django variable as the value attribute of a form field

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I want text to already be in my form when I load it and I thought a good way to do this would be to add a value attribute.  However it is tricky because I am using django forms which generate html after the fact.  So this is the relevant part of how I display my form in my template:

```
<form role="form" action="/editfeedback/{{feedback.id}}/{{board}}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.name == "title" %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"value:THIS IS THE TITLE" }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% elif field.name == "body" %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"value:THIS IS THE BODY" }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {{ field|attr:"value:tag" }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">{% trans "Save" %}</button><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This works well for displaying predetermined text but I have a list of posts and each post has an edit form attached.  My question is: **is there a way I can set the field value attribute to a django variable?**  I have tried `{{ field|attr:"value:{{post.title}}" }}` but that gives me the following error:

> > TemplateSyntaxError
> >
> > attr requires 2 arguments, 1 provided

EDIT: adding EditFeedbackForm from `forms.py` and edit_feedback view from `views.py`

```
class EditFeedbackForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='Title', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    body = forms.CharField(label='Body', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    tags = forms.CharField(label='Tags', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

And my view:

```
@login_required
def edit_feedback(request, feedback_id, board):
    boardObj = Board.objects.get(board_name=board)
    post = Feedback.objects.get(id=feedback_id)
    form = EditFeedbackForm(initial={'title': post.feedback_title, 'body': post.feedback_description})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditFeedbackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            tags = form.cleaned_data['tags']
            post.feedback_title = title
            post.feedback_description = body
            post.feedback_last_modified = datetime.now()
            post.save(update_fields=['feedback_title', 'feedback_description', 'feedback_last_modified'])
            # print "saved feedback " + str(post.id)
    else:
        form = EditFeedbackForm()
    return redirect('/board/' + board + '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, when initializing the form, you can assign initial values:

```
form = WhatsYourFormsClass(initial={'field1': value1, 'field2': value2})
```

**EDIT:**
You initialise the form with initial values correctly:

```
(...)
form = EditFeedbackForm(initial={'title': post.feedback_title, 'body': post.feedback_description})
if (...)
```

but then pass another (empty) instance:

```
(...)
else
    form = EditFeedbackForm()
return (...)
```

Your method should be like that:

```
@login_required
def edit_feedback(request, feedback_id, board):
    boardObj = Board.objects.get(board_name=board)
    post = Feedback.objects.get(id=feedback_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditFeedbackForm(request.POST)
        (form processing)
        (if processing went OK, redirect to your chosen view)
    else:
        form = EditFeedbackForm(initial={'title': post.feedback_title, 'body': post.feedback_description})
    return render(**your form template name here**, {'form': form})
```

Comment: I tried doing `post = Feedback.objects.get(id=feedback_id)` and `form = EditFeedbackForm(initial={'title': post.feedback_title, 'body': post.feedback_description})` and the form fields show up blank but there are no errors.  Would it help to see my edit_feedback view and form?

Comment: Yes, please, I think it will help.

Comment: Okay I added them.  Could the problem be that edit_feedback does not get called until the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Please see edit to my original reply, hope that helps.